# Proper grease for a meat slicer blade

Tags: equipment, fat

I just found an old hand cranked meat slicer which I can use to slice homemade lunch meats. It was free, but it obviously hasn't been used awhile. Inside there are two gears, and a bearing on which the blade spins. I took off the blade to give the thing a through cleaning, and in the process removed all of the grease. I am now running it through the dish washer to give it yet another washing before we use it.

Can anyone suggest a proper grease to use to lubricate the blade? There is a small chance it could come in contact with food so I was thinking a few shots of silicon grease? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm thinking a generous dollop of capicola grease would work and add seasoning to the internal bits of your machine-werks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Food grade lubricants](http://www.machinerylubrication.com/Read/445/food-grade-lubricants)

Looks like there's quite a few [food grade greases available online](http://www.google.com/search?q=food%20grade%20grease&num=20&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=VNo&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&prmd=imvns&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=qY04T9-9Hq6isQKR7O2mAg&ved=0CGkQrQQ&biw=1340&bih=961). Some of them are silicone based. Still, I'd get something that definitely says food grade, rather than whatever's on sale at Ace hardware.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I have a second slicer coming in in just a few days to replace any broken parts, so hopefully I can start using this thing soon.